# SSD Takes a While to Start Up

Tags: windows-10, ssd, sata

when I login to Windows my SSD drive (SanDisk Ultra 1TB) will sometimes not show up as accessible straight away and the whole system kind of gets stuck and when I try to open windows or folders nothing happens until the drive shows up. For example the drive is blank (as show in the picture) and I cannot open task manager, folders or any apps/programs until it shows up, then they all load up at the same time almost like it caused the whole system to lag.

The drive is not new but has been used by me for about 6 months and has been absolutely fine until my most recent re-install of Windows but the whole system worked fine before (I re-installed for a refresh). I know this is sometimes seen in external hard drives like some I own as you have to account for power saving and spin up time but this is not external but a sata drive.

I am very good with computers and always keep all my drivers and programs up to date and have done all the basic checks before asking like checked the cables and plugged it in different sata connectors on the motherboard, make sure it shows up properly in bios, my whole pc was recently re-installed (hence this new issue) so the drive has been formatted before use, checked it for errors, have installed the drivers I normally would but once it shows it works fine and loads games like normal so I am really stuck for answers.

Another small note and possibly unrelated is Uplay does not auto-load on start up and can take ages to load if I open it sometimes, I have Ubisoft games installed on the drive in question and have re-installed Uplay multiple times with no change.

PC Specs:

i9 9900k (stock no oc)

32GB Trident Z RGB 3600Mhz

Gigabyte Z390 Aorus Master (Latest bios: F11c)

MSI GTX 1080 Gaming X

Boot/Main drive: Samsung 960 Evo M.2 NVME 256GB

SSD: SanDisk Ultra 1TB

Windows 10 Pro (2004) (Build: 19041.508)

[image]

Comment: When the drive does not appear on File Explorer does it show up within Disk Management?

Comment: Hi, yes it does, acts as normal, just like it wont start up on windows start for about 2 minutes then bounces into action, so weird its baffled me

Comment: Not related.. WOW THAT IS A LOT OF SPACE!! NNTR

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to fix my problem with the ssd not being recognised in windows for the first 5 minutes but this may not work for everyone with a similar issue but I still think its worth saying as it helped me after I tried everything else.

On the gigabyte bios easymode main screen (different for others or older bios revisions) there is a toggle to turn "intel rapid storage tech" on or off and mine was obviously off as I hear it can only maybe benifit RAID setups etc but I thought I would try it anyway and switched it on and restarted.

Lo and behold it has seemed to resolve my problem so for anyone else in a similar boat please try this, you never know.

many thanks for all who replied.

Comment: Intel RST should never be configured, selected, or enabled in the BIOS or UEFI firmware, _unless_ you're running a RAID configuration set up using Intel RST, as that's the only purpose of it _(Interface type for drives should be set to AHCI))_.